# не могу настроить редирект с папки public/ в laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

настроил .htaccess, перекинул в корень проекта laravel, но выдает ошибку

> error 404 | Not Found

думаю возможно проблема в том что я загрузил проект на поддомене, не создавая отдельный домен в локалке

Comment: что значит "перекинул"? Откуда перекинули?  И почему редирект "с папки", а не "в папку"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. ты используешь OSPanel (на скрине увидел) - зайди в настройки > домены. Там созадай домен и укажи конкретно директорию. Для удобства я лично не использую автоматическое определение доменов, а использую ручное управление.
И не парься с .htaccess
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заработало, спасибо вам большое)